# Linux g++ Embedding Prolog Logic Engine Within C++

Tags: c++, prolog, embed, swi-prolog

I have some logic in a C++ program that is not only insanely complex, it requires multiple solutions for which Prolog is ideal. It's sort of like a firewall config script, checking input for actions, but sometimes more that one action is required.

What I want is something like this:

```
class PrologEngine
{
    LoadLogic(const char* filename) throw PrologException; // Load a file of prolog rules, predicates facts etc in textual format. Must be callable multiple times to load AND COMPILE (for speed) prolog rule files.

    std::vector<std::string> Evaluate(const char* predicate_in_string_form = "execute(input, Result)") throw PrologException; Returns a vector of matching predicates in text form.

};
```

It needs no ability to call back into C++.

AMI Prolog seems to get it, but it's not available on Linux. I'm trying to use SWI-Prolog and can only find 2 examples and and incredibly byzantine API (my opinion)

Can anyone point me to an example that is close to what I'm looking for?

Comment: This blog post has a small example of what you want to do wit swi-prolog: http://electricbacon.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/calc-example-using-swi-prolog-and-c/

Comment: Why not use CLIPS instead of prolog? http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/WhatIsCLIPS.html

Answer (score 4):

There is [A C++ interface to SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/pl2cpp.html), that's high level.

I'm [fighting with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290625/sigsegv-in-dso-mixed-c-c), here an example of bridging to OpenGL:

```
PREDICATE(glEvalCoord1d, 1) {
 double u = A1;
 glEvalCoord1d( u );
 return TRUE;
}
```

This clean code hides many 'bizantinism', using implicit type conversion and some macro. The interface is well tought and bidirectional: to call Prolog from C++ there are PlCall ('run' a query, similar to Evaluate you expose in the answer) or a more structured PlQuery, for multiple results...

If you don't need to link to openGl, or can wait to ear about the answer that hopefully I'll get from SWI-Prolog mailing list, you should evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind rewriting the prolog code for use in a native c++ header only library, I'd look into the castor library:
http://www.mpprogramming.com/cpp/

Comment: Castor it's interesting. Did you tried it? I fear it could be rather inefficient.

Comment: I figured it out. It's quite nice once you figure it out. Writing a predicate in C++ is easy too. Here's the core of it.